# Calculating the shape matrix

Tags: differential-geometry

I am stuck on this problem. I need to calculate the curvatures but my shape matrix is not happening. Any help is appreciated. So far I have done this:

$X(u,v) = (cosv-(u+v)sinv, sinv+(u+v)cosv, u+2v)$

So I take the partial velocities

$X_u = (-sinv,cosv,1)$ and, 
$X_v = (-2sinv-(u+v)cosv, 2cosv-(u+v)sinv,2)$

Taking the cross product gives me:

$((u+v)sinv,-(u+v)cosv,u+v)$

Hence the unit normal is:

=$1/\sqrt{2} (sinv,-cosv,1)$

So the shape operators are

$S_p(X_u) = 0$ and,
$S_p(X_v) = 1/\sqrt2 (cosv,sinv,0)$

This is where I get stuck. How do I calculate the shape matrix from here? If there is a more efficient way that would be enlightening.

Comment: How did you compute $S_p(X_u)$ and $S_p(X_v)$? It's difficult to give you advice without knowing that. Are you not computing the second fundamental form by computing $X_{uu}\cdot n$, $X_{uv}\cdot n$, $X_{vv}\cdot n$?

Comment: I took the negative directional derivative of the unit normal.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, so the matrix of the shape operator $S_p$ (with respect to the basis $\{X_u,X_v\}$) is
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{bmatrix},$$
where $S_p(X_u) = aX_u + bX_v$ and $S_p(X_v) = cX_u + dX_v$.
In your case, you find that $a=b=0$ and $c=-\dfrac{\sqrt2}{u+v}$ and $d=\dfrac1{\sqrt2(u+v)}$. (By the way, you dropped the negative sign in your computation.)

The customary way of computing this is to note that (using $n\cdot X_u = n\cdot X_v = 0$)
\begin{align*}
S_p(X_u)\cdot X_u &= -n_u\cdot X_u = n\cdot X_{uu} \\
S_p(X_u)\cdot X_v &= -n_u\cdot X_v = n\cdot X_{uv} = n\cdot X_{vu} = S_p(X_v)\cdot X_u \tag{$\star$}\\
S_p(X_v)\cdot X_v &= -n_v\cdot X_v = n\cdot X_{vv}.
\end{align*}
You then make the second fundamental form matrix 
$$II = \begin{bmatrix} X_{uu}\cdot n & X_{uv}\cdot n \\ X_{vu}\cdot n & X_{vv}\cdot n\end{bmatrix}$$
and the first fundamental form matrix
$$I = \begin{bmatrix} \|X_u\|^2 & X_u\cdot X_v \\ X_v\cdot X_u & \|X_v\|^2\end{bmatrix},$$
and note that the equations ($\star$) can be written in matrix form as
$$I\begin{bmatrix}a & c\\b& d\end{bmatrix} = II,$$
so $S_p = I^{-1}II$.

(You might want to download my [differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) for more examples and explanations.)

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for your extensive answer!! I will take a look at that, thanks again.